# Three js - Texture control

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures

I have this material

```
"materials": [{
    "colorAmbient": [0.64,0.64,0.64],
    "shading": "phong",
    "mapDiffuseAnisotropy": 1,
    "mapDiffuseWrap": ["RepeatWrapping","RepeatWrapping"],
    "colorDiffuse": [0.64,0.64,0.64],
    "DbgName": "Material",
    "blending": "NormalBlending",
    "colorSpecular": [0.5,0.5,0.5],
    "DbgIndex": 0,
    "depthTest": true,
    "visible": true,
    "colorEmissive": [0,0,0],
    "wireframe": false,
    "mapDiffuseRepeat": [1,1],
    "depthWrite": true,
    "opacity": 1,
    "specularCoef": 50,
    "DbgColor": 15658734,
    "mapDiffuse": "w.jpg",
    "transparent": false
}]
```

where the texture in my object is a parallelogram. I would like the texture to be only in one side of the parallelogram and with the above values that is not happening. How can i make the image be only in one side of my object?

Thanks!

Comment: where the texture falls, depends on the uv coordinates of the object; not on its material.

Comment: thanks @gaitat. After some researce I fell to this tutorial here http://solutiondesign.com/blog/-/blogs/webgl-and-three-js-texture-mappi-1/ that helped me understand some things. I think it has something to do with what you are saying.